# Vanishing theorems that work in positive characteristic

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, cohomology, characteristic-p

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field of characteristic $p>0$ of dimension at least $2$. I am looking for some examples when $H^2(\mathcal{O}_X)$ vanishes. Is there any standard way to produce such examples? Any idea or reference in this direction will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Complete intersections of sufficiently low codimension?

Comment: @Sawin: I do not understand. Is it an answer or a question?

Comment: It is an answer.  See for instance the exercises in Hartshorne on cohomology of complete intersections.  I would also say that the vanishing or non-vanishing of $H^2(O_X)$ isn't necessarily characteristic dependent.  Do you have some class of examples where this vanishing is potentially characteristic dependent (besides the obvious Fano case)?